# Given the transformation $T:\Bbb R^5 \to\Bbb R^2$ where $T(x) = Ax$, how many rows and columns does matrix $A$ have?

Tags: matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, mapping-class-group

> Given the transformation $T:\Bbb R^5 \to\Bbb R^2$ where $T(x) = Ax$, how many rows and columns does matrix $A$ have?

Please tell me the procedure to solve this question.

Comment: The way I read it, you are going from a 5 by 1 vector to a 2 by 1 vector through a matrix multiplication. That should then tell you what the dimensions of the matrix should be in order for this matrix to facilitate the multiplication (and therefore the transformation)

Comment: I’m surprised you haven’t familiarized yourself with the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) yet. See how much better the question looks now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By convention

- $x$ is a $5$-row, $1$-column matrix,
- $A$ is a $2$-row, $5$-column matrix,

allows the multiplication $Ax$ to be defined and

- $Ax$ is a $2$-row, $1$-column matrix.

Parallel to this is the naming, in which rows are said first and columns second. It is said that $x$ is $5\times 1$, $A$ is $2\times 5$, and $Ax$ is a $2\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Nice answer +1)

Answer (score 3):

$T$ maps a $5$-tuple ($R^5$) vector to a $2$-tuple. So $A$ is a $2 \times 5$ matrix. 
Another way to see this is to remember that the image of $T $ is in $R^2$ and its relationship with columns of $A $ (2-tuples). Similarly kernel of $T $ is a subspace of $R^5$ and the number if columns of $A$ must equal $5$.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to provide a numerical example with two vectors and a matrix.